# Is Extreme Muscle Pro safe?

Tags: muscle, gym, supplements, health

I am a nerd and don't have very fit body. I have been going to gym irregularly for the last 3 months, getting a little bit in shape & improving my strength.

Question: Is it safe to take Extreme Muscle Pro as a supplement to make this process faster?

Concerns:

- There is lots of talk & controversy on the internet about this product. I couldn't find right answer, so please answer yes or no and list reasons.
- I am into computer software development and am also worried that if something goes wrong I might lose focus in programming. Any possibility of this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given that the second result for "Xtreme Muscle Pro" in google is for a [scam warning site](http://www.scambook.com/company/view/84686/Xtreme-Muscle-Pro), I'd suggest that even if it is safe, its unlikely to provide the result you need.

The key to muscle growth is: Lift weights *regularly*, eat whole food rich in proteins and vitamins, track your calories and research supplaments if and only if your diet is lacking in things you can't get from food.

Comment: And don't forget the last key: sleep!